# Margin on the bottom of a div when using float left on HTML5

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the following code creates a margin just below the yellow div?. The following code is HTML5 (see the doctype). If you remove the doctype so it's not HTML5 then there is no margin (how I like). The point is that this code must be in HTML5 (that's a requirement for me). Also the yellow div must have width:300px (that's a requirement for me).

Given the circumstances, **how can I get rid of the margin** below the yellow div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:#00f;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:300px;background-color:#ff0;">
            <div style="float:left;">Hello</div>
            <div style="float:right;">World</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check the above code on: https://jsfiddle.net/gscz9ahq/

You have a preview here:

[image]

I have tried using "clear:both;" with no success.

Any idea on how to solve this?
Could you modify the jsfiddle code in order this to work?

Comment: display:inline-block..why are you using that?

Comment: inline-elements have default property of  vertical-align as baseline once changed to middle it will work properly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gscz9ahq/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `display: inline-block;` that creates the space. But your html is a bit off, you need to clearfix the div when using float.

[check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gscz9ahq/3/)

```
<div style="background-color:#00f;">
  <div class="clearfix" style="width:300px;background-color:#ff0;">
    <div style="float:left;">Hello</div>
    <div style="float:right;">World</div>
  </div>
</div>

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To the `<div style="display:inline-block;width:300px;background-color:#ff0;">` div add `vertical-align: top;`